# How to build Visual Studio 2019 C# solution command line invoked from Windows PowerShell or PowerShell ISE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, command-line, build

If I launch Developer PowerShell for VS2019, I can build my C# solution and control is given back when the devenv process exits.

```
$argsList = "/build Debug mysolution.sln"
$process = Start-Process devenv.exe -ArgumentList $argsList -PassThru -Wait
if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "completed"
} else {
    Write-Host "failed"
}
```

I want to be able to do the same from Windows 2016 server PowerShell or PowerShell ISE, so I can debug a more complex script. First, Visual Studio binaries are not in the path, but what bothers me is that the devenv process exits without giving back control after Start-Process.

```
$devenvPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$argsList = "/build Debug mysolution.sln"
$process = Start-Process $devenvPath -WorkingDirectory . -ArgumentList $argsList -PassThru -Wait
if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "completed"
} else {
    Write-Host "failed"
}
```

1. How can I invoke from 'regular' PS the Visual Studio Power shell that comes with extra modules loaded and paths set for my build job?
2. How can I redirect the build output to the PS window? -NoNewWindow passed to Start-Process doesn't do it. I can redirect to a file with 'devenv /Out file' option though.
3. What am I doing wrong that devenv exits but script doesn't come back or comes after a very long time?

Comment: The "Developer PowerShell" developer is just a file link. Have a look at the target and you see the modules loaded etc.

Comment: To 3.) Can you be a bit more specifc? What behavior do you get? How do you see the process "exits"? Also, `start-process` should return the process object immediately. Where exactly does your "script not come back"? And can you try to rephrase that maybe

Comment: start-process is blocked when -Wait flag is passed until process ends. That allows to make sure that build artifacts are ready, so I continue to next step. The problem is that in second case, control is not back to script even after devenv process is gone.